# HTML: Why block element creates Gap

Tags: html, css

I ve created a HTML template with a header, menu and content section:

[image: Code without block element]

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
#header {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
 height: 85px;
}
#below-header {
 background-color: yellow;
 position: relative;
 height: 200px;
}
#menu {
 background-color: blue;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
}
#content {
 padding-left: 200px;  /* menu */
 background-color: green;
 height: 150px;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="below-header">
   <div id="menu">menu</div>
   <div id="content">content</div>
   below-header
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

But when inserting a block-element with an margin (e.g. a h1 tag), there is a ugly gap:

[image: Code with block element]

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
#header {
 background-color: red;
 width: 100%;
 height: 85px;
}
#below-header {
 background-color: yellow;
 position: relative;
 height: 200px;
}
#menu {
 background-color: blue;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 150px;
}
#content {
 padding-left: 200px;  /* menu */
 background-color: green;
 height: 150px;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="below-header">
   <div id="menu">menu</div>
   <div id="content">
    <h1>headline in content</h1>
   </div>
   below-header
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

When removing the margin or converting the h1 element to an `inline-block` element, the gap is gone.

Comment: [Collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) are what's bothering you here

Comment: h1 usually has a default margin so you need to remove it